# Инициализация при помощи ArrayList

Tags: java

В чем отличие результата инициализации первой записи от второй

```
List list = new ArrayList();
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: попробуйте у `list` и `arrayList` поставить точку и посмотреть какие методы автокомплит предложит использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом примере

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

создается объект типа `List`, а во втором

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

объект типа `ArrayList`. Это возможно, т.к. класс `ArrayList` реализует интерфейс `List`.
Но есть одно но - в первом примере не будут доступны методы класса ArrayList, а только методы типа `List`, т.к. объект типа `List`, в то время, как во втором примере методы ArrayList будут доступны.
А чтобы из объекта `List` создать объект `ArrayList`, достаточно ввести

```
ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) list;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List list;
```

Представляет собой любой объект реализующий интерфейс List. В Вашем случае это ArrayList, но чтобы воспользоваться специфическими методами этого класса, нужно будет приводить типы.

```
(ArrayList) list
```

В Вашем втором примере Вы сразу получаете переменную типа `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

Это всё, если кратко. Более подробно есть хорошая [статья](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/5.2.php).